# How to show total value with legend in Fustion Chart

Tags: fusioncharts

By Using Fusion Chart am able to show the 2d donut chart after reading the documentation provided by fusion chart but in below code i am using legend on left hand side where i want related data to be displayed **just below the legend label**.

For example my label in this code is `Electric Power Generation` and it value is `20` so i want this 20 to be shown below the legend label.

If it is possible , please let me know how to do that.

```
<html>
  <head>        
    <title>My First chart using FusionCharts - Using JavaScript</title>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>     
    <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
     <div id="chartContainer1" style="margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: -22%;">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

      var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Doughnut2D.swf", 
                    "myChartId", "500", "300",  "0", "0");
var dataString ='<chart caption="View Indusries" showLabels="0" showValues="0" showLegend="1"  legendPosition="RIGHT" chartrightmargin="40" bgcolor="ECF5FF" bgalpha="70" bordercolor="C6D2DF"\n\
 basefontcolor="2F2F2F" basefontsize="11" showpercentvalues="1" bgratio="0" startingangle="200" animation="1">\n\
 <set value="20" label="Electric Power Generation" color="005C8E"/>\n\
 <set value="32" label="Industrial Processes" color="00759B"/>\n\
 <set value="12" label="Residential and Commercial Activities" color="0296D2"/>\n\
 <set value="20" label="Agriculture" color="40C7F9"/>\n\
 <set value="2" label="Waste Disposal" color="00496C"/>\n\
 </chart>';
  myChart.setXMLData( dataString );
 myChart.render("chartContainer"); 

    // -->  
    </script>      
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: To display value just below the legend label, try using the following code: <set value="20" label="Electric Power Generation{br} 20" displayValue="Electric Power Generation" color="005C8E"/>

Comment: @Swarram It is not working for me but i have modified the code which works for me. Instead of putting {br} , please put \r\.

Comment: @Swarram Can i use that value with some style and color because requirement is label and value should be of diffrent color.

Comment: No, it is not possible to provide different style /color for label/value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this which is given below

```
var toalval = 20000;
<set value="20" label="Electric Power Generation \r\ '+dsa+'" displayValue="Electric Power Generation" color="005C8E"/>\n\
```